# Aren't there reaction forces acting on weightless connected rods?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

In my applied mathematics class, our teacher told us that there are no reaction forces acting on a weightless connected rods. But, as in the this picture,

[image: as in the this picture]

I have a weightless rod ($AB$) hinged
to a wall by $A$, and ($BC$) rod which has a weight of $W$ is held in equilibrium with a  $T$ horizontal force. My question is, if there are no reaction forces with a weightless rod (I've shown those forces as $x$ and $y$) ,when considering the system $BC$, how would the rod $BC$ stay in equilibrium.

Sorry if this is a silly question. I know weightless rods are ideal, but, I need a clarification on this.

Comment: @Ibrahim I thought this was math related. I learned this in my math class.

Comment: What kind of problem is this, why would you want a weightless rod? are they just floating?

Comment: When did your instructor say "*there are no reaction forces acting on a weightless connected rods*" and in what context?